# Значение строки пропадает странным образом

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия

```
def PrintList(seq):
    string = ''
    for num in seq:
        if isinstance(num, list):
            string += '2^(' + str(PrintList(num)) + ')'
            continue
        else:
            string += '2^' + str(num)
            if seq.index(num) == len(seq) - 1:
                print(string)
                return string
print(str(PrintList([[1, 0]])))
```

Судя по последним двум строчкам функции, должно вывести 2^12^0 два раза, первый раз с `print(string)` второй с возврата этой строчки из функции. Если с первым вариантом всё хорошо, то с возвратом уже плохо. Возвращает почему-то `None`, хотя прошлой строчкой можно проверить, что это не так. Уже долго копаюсь и не могу понять проблему.
Результат этой функции:

```
2^12^0
None
```

Ожидается:

```
2^12^0
2^12^0
```

Comment: По вашему, что будет когда цикл завершится, а условие `if seq.index(num) == len(seq) - 1:` не будет выполнено?

Comment: Кст, а как ваш код должен был отработать? Напишите, пожалуйста, в вопросе входные данные и ожидаемый результат

Comment: Прошу заметить, что мой код работает правильно только до момента с возвратом из функции, который должен выдавать то же значение что и print внутри функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш алгоритм пишет `None` в

```
2^12^0
None
```

потому что у `PrintList` выход после цикла не указан.

Объясняю по шагам:

- Вызываете вы `PrintList([[1, 0]])`
- В цикле `num` будет иметь `[1, 0]` и оно пройдет проверку `if isinstance(num, list):`, провалившись в себя, т.е. будет вызвано `PrintList([1, 0])`
- В `PrintList([1, 0])` в цикле `num` будет иметь значение `1`, провалит проверку `if isinstance(num, list):` и попадет в вторую ветку, где выполнится `print(string)` `return string`. Функция `PrintList([1, 0])` тут завершается и результат возвращается в первый вызов
- Результат предыдущего шага попадет в `string += '2^(' + str(PrintList(num)) + ')'` и цикл завершится
- Функция `PrintList([[1, 0]])` завершается и т.к. у нее нет своего `return`, будет по умолчанию возвращено `None`

Код:

```
def PrintList(seq):
    string = ''
    for num in seq:
        if isinstance(num, list):
            string += '2^(' + str(PrintList(num)) + ')'
            continue
        else:
            string += '2^' + str(num)
            if seq.index(num) == len(seq) - 1:
                print(string)
                break

    return string

print(PrintList([[1, 0]]))
```

Консоль:

```
2^12^0
2^(2^12^0)
```